# Añadir valores absolutos a las etiquetas de cada porción de matplotlib.pyplot.pie

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Buen día, estoy construyendo una gráfica y me aparecen solo los porcentajes en las etiquetas de cada porción, quisiera agregar también los valores juntos con los porcentajes. ¿Eso es posible?

Ahora mismo hago lo siguiente:

```
df.column.value_counts().plot(kind='pie', fontsize=15,figsize=(7, 7),
                              autopct='%1.1f%%', legend = True)
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: Buen dìa, estoy construyendo una grafica y me aparecen solo los porcentajes en las etiquetas de datos, quisiera agregar los valores juntos con los porcentajes. ¿Eso es posible?
Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es posible hacer lo que quieres de forma relativamente simple, `autopct` es un argumento de [`matplotlib.pyplot.pie`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html?highlight=autopct) que admite una cadena de formato (tal como tu le pasas) pero también un callable. En ambos casos  es usado para formatear la etiqueta de cada "quesito".

Sabiendo esto, con la ayuda de una función de orden superior y un iterador es muy simple de conseguir:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframe con datos aleatorios de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame({"column": np.random.random_integers(5, size=(137,))})

def autopct_fun(abs_values):
    gen = iter(abs_values)
    return lambda pct: f"{pct:.1f}% ({next(gen)})"

counts = df.column.value_counts()

counts.plot(kind='pie',
            fontsize=15,
            figsize=(7, 7),
            autopct=autopct_fun(counts),
            legend = True
            )

plt.show()
```

Como cada porción se construye en el mismo orden en el que están los valores iterable, solo debemos de preocuparnos de que cada vez que se llama a la función ésta formatee la cadena y la retorne usando el valor absoluto que le toca (que en la primera llamada use primer valor de la serie, que en la segunda use el segundo y así sucesivamente). Para ello usamos el iterador, que será consumido por la función anónima retornada por la función de orden superior `autopct_fun` (y que es la que usa `matplotlib.pyplot.pie` para formatear las etiquetas, llamándola una vez para cada porción) para agregar el valor absoluto correspondiente a cada porcentaje (porcentaje que matplotlib le pasa mediante el argumento `pct`) a la cadena de retorno.

El resultado es algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el valor absoluto aparece entre paréntesis al lado de su valor relativo correspondiente, de acuerdo al formato que especificamos.

Se puede conseguir lo mismo sin usar una función de orden superior (que recibe o retorna otra función), pero requiere del uso de variables globales y es recomendable siempre reducir su uso en lo posible.

> **Advertencia**
>
> Si se usa Python < 3.6 no se puede hacer uso de los literales de cadena formateados (f-strings). En ese caso se puede usar `str.format` en su lugar:
>
> ```
> return lambda pct: "{:.1f}% ({})".format(pct, next(gen))
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me funciona perfecto.